# SSL hostname.bundle error in python script

Tags: python, ssl

we have a python script running on a centos web panel machine designed to start up a Git interface

this was working fine till the hostname ssl expired yesterday

we replaced the hostname.cert and hostname.key and hostname.bundle with a new wildcard digicert ssl and restarted all services but get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hosting/scripts/git-web-interface/server.py", line 12, in <module>
    certificate_chain = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.bundle"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cheroot/ssl/builtin.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.context.load_cert_chain(certificate, private_key)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the file being executed is:

```
# Our stuff
import customGlobals
# Web.py
import web

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from cheroot.server import HTTPServer
    from cheroot.ssl.builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter
    HTTPServer.ssl_adapter = BuiltinSSLAdapter(
        certificate = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.cert",
        private_key = "/etc/pki/tls/private/hostname.key",
        certificate_chain = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.bundle"
    )
    customGlobals.app.run()
```

we have triple checked that the cert, key and chain paths are correct and the files exist with the right ownership but its saying the hostname.bundle is incorrect

anyone know what's going on here?

the hostname.bundle appears to be just a copy of the cert file, so im guessing that's not right but i don't know what it should be if its not that?

can anyone advise?

Comment: *"we have triple checked that the cert, key and chain paths are correct and the files exist with the right ownership"* - Hm, "No such file or directory" clearly says otherwise.

Comment: yes you'd think that would be the case but....

```
[root@server1 ~]# locate hostname.cert
/etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.cert
[root@server1 ~]# locate hostname.key
/etc/pki/tls/private/hostname.key
[root@server1 ~]# locate hostname.bundle
/etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.bundle
[root@server1 ~]#
```

and all files chowned as root:root @ 644